# Remove the load of buck converter

Tags: current, inductor, buck

I have a buck converter that is delivering 6A to a load of 3ohm load.

I'm measuring the output current and stop increasing the dutty cicle when the current reach 6A, at this moment the output voltage will  be 18V. A few second after reaching this point the resistance will break and I will have and open circuit at the ouput.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5E1T6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My concern is the following, the inductor's current can't change inmediatly, I guess I'll go to the capacitor increasing the output voltage, It is a risk to damage the power supply or the driver circuit because of a backward current?

I'm using a IR2110 to drive the transistor.

[image]

Edit:

R1 is a heating wire, I'll use it to control the ignition of a small rocket, so at the moment of the ignition the wire will break and the inductor will be is series with the capacitor.

Now, I just made this calculations:

$$ capacitor \ energy  = 0.5*C*V^2 $$

$$ inductor \ energy  = 0.5*L*I^2 $$

$$ L = 43uH \ , \  I = 6A $$
$$ \ C = 800uF $$

$$ inductor \ energy  = 0.001548 $$

for 0.001548 joules I get:

$$ \Delta_V = 2V $$

Is It that an accurate estimation?

Edit 2:

Is this scenario of removing the load different than operating in discontinuous conduction mode? where the current ripple is high and adsorbed for the capacitor.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What part is failing? What is backward current? Do you mean back-EMF? Your synopsis is a bit confusing. Please clarify your question, or if more than one question please list them.

Comment: Do you realize that R1 is dissipating 108 watts. You may need to use a 300 watt wire-wound resistor for R1. Was that the only issue you had?

Comment: @Sparky256 I just edit the question to clarify that. I'm using kanthal wire, it puts red hot.

Comment: What do other rocket people do? I think I would prefer to use a linear current regulator (with a few transistors), or even a big power resistor. You could still control the timing with a FET. Even though the linear circuit will dissipate a lot of power, it doesn't have to do it for very long, so big heavy parts will probably last through many cycles. Also, if you lowered the supply to 18V, you wouldn't need any current limiting circuitry...

Comment: @mkeith Yes use a linear regulator would be an easier solution, but at this point is very complicated for me to change the approach.

Comment: In that case I think you make this solution work.

Comment: How are you switching the transistor on? You will need to drive it to over 30V  (around 35V) to make sure it turns on. You will have to be careful with turning it off, too. Max Vgs is +/- 20V. If you exceed that, there is a good chance you will damage it. It might be a bit easier to use PMOS.

Comment: @mkeith I'm using an IR2110 to drive the transistor I added an image with the connection. Shouldn't the driver's bootstrap be able to handle that situation?

Comment: Have you considered using simple PWM switching, with no inductor &c?

Comment: @JimmyB to have a dc output was a condition.

Comment: Ok, but "DC" to what extent? How much ripple at which frequency is tolerated?

Comment: @JimmyB Higher than 60Hz, no ripple tolerance was specified.

Comment: IRF2110 should be OK, based on quick look at the datasheet. Now that I think about it blowing the wire quickly is really not the goal. You want to heat up the grain until it ignites. So limiting the current could be a very important requirement because it will allow the hot wire to transfer heat for a longer duration. I still think PWMing the output without the LC could work, but if you want DC current, then your original approach is probably still the best, considering everything. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, You're right, blowing the wire isn't the goal, is a consequence of the ignition, and I'm actually checking the output current that's other reason of way I'm using a converter instead of a pure pwm control, is easier to get the feedback  with a dc output. thanks, in fact we make a test yesterday but not with the would rocket just the igniter we converter worked but in this case the wire didn't broke, this one is wider than the  wires used previously. We will make another test tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulas are correct, but I'm not sure where you are getting your numbers from.

Based on the 18V output voltage, the capacitor energy at the time of the break is 129.6mJ and you are adding 0.77mJ to it, so the capacitor voltage will change from 18V to 18.054V if all the energy of a pulse finds its way into the capacitor. Of course if more pulses come along that will add up quickly at 100kHz.

In general, \$\Delta V = -V +\sqrt{V^2 + I^2(\frac{L}{C})}\$

Comment: The OP's stated output voltage is 18 volts @ 6 amps, until R1 intentionally blows.

Comment: @Sparky256 Okay, will be even less. I'll go get my specs and recalculate.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The numbers are from the circuit diagram, I don't have any issue if vo reach 30V when there is no load, I can turn off the converter manually, my concern is regarding the transient state  just before R1 blows up, there is any change of Vo been bigger than Vi? or any other  side effect that could damage the circuit?

Comment: There should be no bad effect provided the converter shuts down immediately, which it should, assuming voltage feedback from the output capacitor C1. C1 absorbs the inductor energy from one cycle easily. It may spark due to the energy in the stray inductance on the output- it would be good to minimize that loop area.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't have voltage feedback, I've current feedback from the output current where is the Amp meter, but is much more slower than the switching frequency because I'm also sending and receiving data from a computer, I'm controlling  the converter remotetly. Besides the power loss, what could happend if I put other resistor of 15 ohm or so  in parallel? so I don't have an open circuit.

Comment: Does the charged up capacitor represent a hazard? I mean, if the cap is charged to 18V or 30V, and a user attaches another ignitor to it, that ignitor may go off instantly as the energy in the capacitor is discharged through it. At a minimum, a bleeder resistor is needed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Isn't the output voltage limited to reach  the same voltage as the input source?  given that the inductor'  energy  will produce a delta V of less than 1V should the current stop flow when Vo = Vi?

Comment: @mkeith 30V isn't a big issue once the first load has been used, we will not attach other ignitor quickly, and I think there isn't enough energy to heat the wire,  but is good to have that in mind.

Comment: Yes, limited to input voltage plus a bit.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, OK, but put a resistor in parallel with cap to make sure it discharges over time. Calculate the dissipation to make sure it is OK (don't exceed the resistor limit).

Comment: Ok perfect, I'll do.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why there is a '-' sign in the equation? are all the voltages referred of the capacitor?

Comment: It's the change so the initial voltage is subtracted

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, two more questions. First, why do you have to limit the current to 6A? If you just apply 30V to the ignitor, it will still work, won't it? It will just operate that much faster.

Seccond, if that is not acceptable for some reason, another idea is to use PWM control on the output, but get rid of the inductor and capacitor. Then you will have a voltage square wave. If you use 18/30 duty cycle, this will deliver the same power to the load as 6A of DC. The current will not be smoothed out, as it is when the LC filter is present.

Comment: @mkeith Those was the requirements of the design, to increase the voltage progressively and to have a dc output, stop at that current value was a condition too. The decision of use a converter was mine, I thought  that make a linear regulator would be rather boring.